# The <noun> of <noun>

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles, definite-articles

I wonder about the `the <noun> of <noun>` template. For example, `the customers of a movie theater` or `the possessor of a car`. The question is "Is it a stable rule in English to put "the" before the first noun in this template?" Are there other instances of using this template, but without "the". I often use the structure "`It is the <noun> of <noun>`." For example, "It is the case of a cruel corruption." I have the same questions for this template.

Comment: It's just *a* ***matter*** of ***time*** before someone answers this question.

Comment: `For all customers of the movie theater` doesn't use "the" before the first noun, nor the phrase `I am a customer of the theater`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the asker left the site almost 10 years ago and therefore cannot be expected to improve the question.

Answer (score 5):

The first noun in the *[noun] of [noun]* unit is treated as any other noun as regards modifiers, so (barring special cases such as idioms) wherever you would say *the [noun1]*, you can also say *the [noun1] of [noun2]*, etc.

As a corollary, it is also correct to use *[noun1] of [noun2]* without a *the*, especially if *the* wouldn't normally appear before *[noun1]* alone.  Examples:

> I drink **a cup of coffee** every morning.
>
> **Strength of will** is important in a leader.

Answer (score -1):

*The* is used before names consisting of: noun + of + noun.

Example:

> The bay of Bengal

Comment: The question was addressing a broader use of the constuction than just names.

Answer (score -2):

When the noun is followed by the preposition "of", the definite article is mandatory, for example, "I have sometimes thought that **the mere hearing of** those songs would do more to impress some minds with **the horrible character** of slavery, than **the reading** of whole volumes of philosophy on the subject could do".

Comment: "A reading of the will is to be held on Monday. For those who cannot attend, another reading of the will is to take place on Tuesday." Here, *reading* functions as a noun and follows the normal rules about determiners.